# How to disable </td> selection with specific class with js/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I have my Calendar constructed with html table, where few of the dates can only be  selectable. So i need to disable all the other data.

**Function that highlights the td :**

```
/* Get all rows from your 'table' but not the first one 
        * that includes headers. */
var rows = $('td').not(':first');

/* Create 'click' event handler for rows */
rows.on('click', function (e) {

  /* Get current row */
  var row = $(this);

  /* Check if 'Ctrl', 'cmd' or 'Shift' keyboard key was pressed
            * 'Ctrl' => is represented by 'e.ctrlKey' or 'e.metaKey'
            * 'Shift' => is represented by 'e.shiftKey' */

  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.shiftKey) {
    /* If pressed highlight the other row that was clicked */
    row.addClass('highlight');
  } else {
    /* Otherwise just highlight one row and clean others */
    rows.removeClass('highlight');
    row.addClass('highlight');
  }

});
```

Now suppose my table looks like below :

```
<table>
    <th class='weekday'>Mon</th><th class='weekday'>Tue</th><th class='weekday'>Wed</th>

    <tr class='selectable'> 1</tr>    
    <tr class='selectable'> 2</tr>    
    <tr class='unselectable'> 3</tr>
</table>
```

So now how to disable the tr, with unselectable calss using js/css?

Comment: You're not using <td>'s. Don't put html / data in <tr>s

Comment: where is `<td>` tag in your `html` code sir :) better to use class selector to build your logic. its a better way to do this I think

Comment: What you mean by _disable the tr_?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to validate your HTML code by adding `<td>` tags inside the `<tr>` instead of adding the text directly to the row and adding the `<th>` tags inside the `<tr>` :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class='weekday'>Mon</th>
        <th class='weekday'>Tue</th>
        <th class='weekday'>Wed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='selectable'> 
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class='selectable'> 
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class='unselectable'>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by disable tr since the `disable` attribute work just for `<input>` tag.

You could add class called `unselectable` for example and add the css you want to use for "disabled tr", check example bellow :

```
.unselectable{
     background-color: #ddd;
     cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```css
.unselectable{
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th class='weekday'>Mon</th>
    <th class='weekday'>Tue</th>
    <th class='weekday'>Wed</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='selectable'> 
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr class='selectable'> 
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr class='unselectable'>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your selection on your event

```
 var rows = $('td .selectable');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.unselectable').prop("disabled",true)
```

This will disable the `<tr>` elements with class `unselectable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = $('tr .selectable').not(':first');
```

use the above line to get rows with class name 'selectable'. Also add `<td>` tags inside your `<tr> </tr>` row tags to add contents.

Comment: var rows = $('td .selectable').not(':first'); but its not working, though its behaving something like non of the rows are being selected now

Comment: If your HTML code is same as the above, then there is no <td> tags in your code. So if you use  $('td .selectable').not(':first');   obviously it does not work. I have mentioned "tr" instead of "td" . Please check that and if it does not work still, lets try something else

Answer (score 0):

you can use it  and write your condition instead of below **condition** text =>

```
<td [style.cursor]="condition ? 'not-allowed':'pointer' ">
```