# How to disabled the <td> based on the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="haha"  id="X" >
<td style="width: 5%;" class="haha"><svg class="teeth svg" id="svg"
 width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <!-- upper right 8 -->
    <g id="molar-group" class="molar">
        <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="disto-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="200" y="75" stroke="black" id="mesio-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
 </g>
</svg></td>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {
  ($("#X").keyup(function (){
      if ($("#X").val() == 'X') {
          ('.haha').prop('disabled',true);
      }else{
          ('.haha').prop('disabled', false);
      }
  })
 };
);
```

How to disable the td class="haha" based on the input field. For example, if I type X in the input field it automatically disabled the td class="haha" is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable </td> selection with specific class with js/css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553568/how-to-disable-td-selection-with-specific-class-with-js-css)

Comment: no sir but the answer below that solved my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `disable td` since the disable attribute work just for `<input> tag` .However
You can do something like adding and removing class depending upon your condition.

```js
$("#X").keyup(function (){
      if ($("#X").val() == 'X') {
          $('.haha').addClass('unselectable');
      }else{
          $('.haha').removeClass('unselectable');
      }
  })
```

```css
#svg{
 border : 1px solid green;
}

.unselectable{
     background-color: #ddd;
     cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  
   <input type="text" name="haha" placeholder="enter X to see result" id="X" >
<td style="width: 5%;" class="haha"><svg class="teeth svg" id="svg"
 width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <!-- upper right 8 -->
    <g id="molar-group" class="molar">
        <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="disto-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
        <rect x="200" y="75" stroke="black" id="mesio-occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="125" height="150" fill="white"/>
 </g>
</svg></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[see similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553568/how-to-disable-td-selection-with-specific-class-with-js-css)

Comment: @JohnErickCuizon glad to help .